# How to replace an integer with a character, arrays, loops, Java

Tags: java, arrays, loops, for-loop

I'm new to Java, currently, I'm learning arrays and loops. I have a task, and I don't know what to do, I would use some help.

> Write a Stars class.
> In this class, declare a count field of type int - the number of
> stars.
>
> Redefine the toString method in the Stars class. It should return the
> number of stars in the format accepted by the Intergalactic Guild of
> Spacewalkers.
>
> 1000 stars - X character,
> 100 stars - Y character,
> 10 stars - Z character,
> 1 star - *.
>
> A few examples:
>
> 1001 stars - X*,
> 576 stars - YYYYYZZZZZZZ******,
> The minimum number of characters must be used.
> That is, for example, 101 stars must be represented as Y*, but not as
> ZZZZZZZZZZ*.

I made a template, but unfortunately, I don't know how to make all the calculations.

```
public class Stars {

    int count;

    public int getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    public void setCount(int count) {
        this.count = count;
    }
    
    @Override
    public String toString() {  
        return Integer.toString(count);
    }
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Stars stars = new Stars();
        stars.setCount(2253); // ZZZ***
        System.out.println(stars);
        System.out.println(stars.getCount());
    }
}
```

I had an idea to create an array of numbers 1000, 100, 10, 1, then count how many of them are used.

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to turn 1000 into X I have no idea, whether 2 in **.

Please check my draft, maybe you can give me some advice or hint.

```
public class Test {

    public static void stars(int amount)
    {
        int[] number = new int[]{ 1000, 100, 10, 1 };
        int[] numberCounter = new int[4];
      
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (amount >= number[i]) {
                numberCounter[i] = amount / number[i];
                amount = amount - numberCounter[i] * number[i];
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            if (numberCounter[i] != 0) {
                System.out.print(numberCounter[i]);
            }
        }
    }
     
    public static void main(String argc[]){
        int amount = 2253; // should be : XXYYZZZZZ***
        stars(amount);
    }
}
// Or maybe I can use this formula, thank you
//int units = count % 10;
//int tens = (count / 10) % 10;
//int hundreds = (count / 100) % 10;
//int thousands = (count / 100) % 10;
```

Comment: Variant of "change making problem." Google that for ideas. Stack Overflow isn't really the place to have someone hand-hold you through an assignment. Post here when you have specific technical problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would work :

```
 int x = 101;
StringBuilder builder= new StringBuilder();
    while (x>1000) {
        builder.append("X");
        x-=1000;
    }
    while (x<1000&&x>100) {
        builder.append("Y");
        x-=100;
    }
    while (x<100&&x>10) {
        builder.append("Z");
        x-=10;
    }
    while (x<10 && x!=0) {
        builder.append("*");
        x-=1;
    }
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
```

the point is as long the number of stars is in an interval append a character to the string and then reduce the number.

Comment: You can delete all the less than checks: They are redundant. ie `while (x>100)` is all that's needed.

Comment: Hi @Ellie Azoury! Much appreciate for help, thank you, I've been stuck in this for a whole day, thanks again =D

Comment: @OrestDymarchuk unfortunately this answer has largely robbed you of the chance to learn - see [Open letter to students with homework problems](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6166). Elie next time  you answer a homework question, consider offering general advice or pseudo code etc to leave room for the asker, and future readers, to learn to code.

Comment: Hi @Bohemian, thank you, currently, I'm trying to solve it by myself using for loop, I want to do it by myself, I've just needed a hint or advice.    String thousands = "X";
  String hundreds = "Y";
  String tens = "Z";

  int[] number = new int[] { 1000, 100, 10, 1 };
  int[] numberCounter = new int[4];

  for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
   if (amount >= number[i]) {
    numberCounter[i] = amount / number[i];
    amount -= numberCounter[i] * number[i];
   }
  }
  
  for (int i = 0; i < numberCounter[0]; i++) {
   System.out.print(thousands.repeat(i));
  }

Comment: Hi guys! Thank you for your support, I made it by myself! =)